# percent symbol in mtext

Tags: r, label, bar-chart

I am sure this will be an easy solution for the more skilled than myself.

I am using `mtext` function in R to produce a label in a figure.

I need to add the `'%'` symbol to the text but for the life of me cannot work out how to do this.

My code is below. I have added `symbol(p)` to the code for where I want to add the `'%'` symbol.

The `symbol(p)` command lets me add a `pi` symbol. I presume if I can add a `pi` symbol I should be able to add a `%` symbol.

```
mtext(expression(stems~(symbol(p))),side=2, line=3.0, cex=1.3)
```

Comment: As in `expression(stems ~ '%')`?

Comment: From `?symbol`: *symbol(x)  draw x in symbol font*

Comment: `expression(symbol("%"))` works.

Comment: Oh my! It really was that easy haha

Comment: @DarrenTsai To see the difference try `expression(symbol("%") ~ stems ~ '%')`. I like `symbol("%")`.